# SQL query how to divide two selects that return multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, metabase

I have the following table :

| city | state | numOrder | date | deadlineDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NY | NY | 111 | 2022/11/05 | 2022/11/06 |
| LA | CA | 222 | 2022/11/01 | 2022/10/01 |
| SD | CA | 333 | 2022/05/05 | 2022/11/06 |
| LA | CA | 444 | 2022/11/01 | 2022/05/01 |

I need to calculate the number of orders placed before the deadline divided by the number of orders placed by each state and city:

```
(SELECT state, city ,count(*) 
FROM orders
WHERE date <= deadlineDate
group by state, city) /
(SELECT state, city ,count(*) 
FROM orders
group by state, city)
```

I tried:

```
SELECT (
         SELECT state, city ,count(*) 
         FROM orders 
         WHERE serviceDate <= limitDate 
         group by state, city
       )/
       (
         SELECT state, city ,count(*) 
         FROM orders 
         group by state, city
       )
FROM orders
```

But the I got ERROR:

> Subquery must return only one column

Comment: It's very confusing having a table named *database*

Comment: it was just an example, changed to orders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SELECT state, city, 
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE date <= deadlineDate)*1.0 / COUNT(*) AS result
FROM orders
GROUP BY state, city
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/z6jCuvV3).

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables as two subquery tables and do the math in the select

```
SELECT A.COL1/B.COL1 AS MY_RATIO_COL
FROM
  (SELECT COL1 FROM MY_TABLE WHERE [BLA BLA BLA]) A
  JOIN
  (SELECT COL1 FROM MY_TABLE WHERE [yata yata]) B
  ON A.KEYCOL1 = B.KEYCOL1
```